# C first fgets() is being skipped while the second runs

Tags: c, fgets

The question is:

Why does the first fgets statement is being skipped?
I read somewhere that it might be because of SCANF() that I used before.
I am trying to figure it out but I can't.
Can someone give me the solution (I should probably re-write the first bit of code to avoid scanf, but how?).

This in the code I am struggling with:

```
for(;;)
    {
            //Ask if the user wants to add another CD - Y/N
            fputs("\nWould you like to enter new CDs details?  y or n\n", stdout);
            scanf(" %c" ,&type);
            if (toupper(type) != 'Y')
                break;

            puts("");


            //getting in the album information        
            printf("\tLets enter the details of the CD %d:\n\n", count + 1);


            fputs("Title?\n", stdout);   

            //this fgets statement is being skipped
            fgets(title[count], sizeof title[count], stdin);
            title[count][strlen(title[count]) - 1] = '\0';

            fputs("Atrist? \n", stdout);
            fgets(artist[count], sizeof artist[count], stdin);
            artist[count][strlen(artist[count]) - 1] = '\0';
    }
```

Comment: Don't mix `scanf()` and `fgets()`. Use only `fgets()` for user input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the last `ENTER` keypress, which causes a `newline` is left in the input buffer. This is picked up by the first `fgets()`.

You can add a `while(getchar() != '\n');` before the first `fegts()` to avoid this.

[**EDIT:** Or, for better, as mentioned by Chux <sup>Thanks to him</sup>  in below comment,use something like

```
int ch; while((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF);
```

to handle the 'newline' as well as `EOF`.]

That said, it is never a good choice to mix `scanf()` and `fgets()`. Use `fgets()` always, it is possible and better.

Comment: Maybe `int ch; while((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF);` to prevent infinite loop of `while(getchar() != '\n');` on end-of-file.

Comment: @chux Done, updated. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's because your `scanf()`  didn't read more than a single character, but the user pressed return. The return remains in the input buffer, so `fgets()` immediately sees that and returns.

Don't mix them, use only `fgets()`.

Answer (score 0):

Simply change

```
scanf(" %c" ,&type);
```

to

```
scanf(" %c%*c" ,&type);
```

The reason that the first `fgets` gets skipped is that your `scanf` leaves a newline character in the `stdin`. `fgets` sees this character and consumes it, thus not waiting for furthur input.

The `%*c` tells `scanf` to read and discard a character.

Comment: Thanks guys! Very helpful tips. I am going to look through the forum more carefully next time!